# Who do you think is I/me/you in the picture?

Tags: copular-verbs

Do you think it's correct to use the verb **to be** this way in these sentences?

```
1 Who do you think is me in the picture?

2 Who do you think is you in the picture?

3 How can I recognize who is you in this crowd?
```

I happen to hear natives' opinion that they are not correct. They should be:

```
4 Who do you think I am in the picture?

5 Who do you think you are in the picture?

6 How can I recognize who you are in this crowd?
```

Comment: All 6 sentences are grammatical.

Comment: What's the difference in semantics?

Comment: Note that "Who do you think you are" has an entirely different idiomatic meaning.

Answer (score 3):

All your 6 examples are grammatical.

I would read #1 as meaning something like "of all the people in the picture, which one is me? can you guess?".

I feel #4 has a broader range of possible interpretations. #4 could mean something like "Who do you think I am (pretending to be)?" or "Who do you think I am (representing)?"